# What does the value of R_t represent in Balanis' bowtie antenna design equations?

Tags: rf, analog, antenna, microwave, pcb-antenna

I'm using Antenna Theory: Analysis and Design by Constantine Balanis to aid in the design of a wideband antenna. I believe a bowtie antenna will satisfy my necessary bandwidth, however Balanis notes that the bowtie design equations are derived from the patch antenna design equations. I chose to start there with my study, and Balanis provides detailed derivations for most equations that aren't empirically derived.

However, he provides no detailed derivation for the bowtie design equations from the patch design equations:

[image: Bowtie Design Equations]

The value for R<sub>t</sub> in equation 9-15b appears to represent an impedance based on naming convention but I would like to know what it represents as it appears to be very small (<<1) when I implement these equations. I'm hoping it bears some relation to input impedance (R<sub>in</sub> elsewhere in the text) so that I can use it for tuning my design.